# Is used content of memory saved to disk during suspension?

Tags: 14.04, power-management, battery

When suspending 14.04 on a laptop, 
is the used part of the main memory saved to the disk? I.e. is suspension save-to-ram or save-to-disk?

If yes,

- saved to the swap partition or other partition?
- isn't it true that after suspension, the laptop still needs battery to sustain power supply to the memory to keep its content? If the battery runs out of power, doesn't the content of memory lost forever? So why is content  of memory saved to the disk?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The suspension you see in you shutdown / switch-user menu is suspend to ram. Suspend to disk is by default disabled except if you have a computer for which Canonical has tested this feature.

Therefore, the content of your ram isn't written on the disk and the system needs power to keep refreshing the ram or else the ram will loose all information saved in it.

Comment: Thanks. Is content of ram also not swapped to swap partition? Why is the swap partition size needed to be one or twice the size of ram?

Comment: The content of the ram is saved to the swap partition for suspend to disk. Then there needs to be more space than your ram is big + what's already swapped. But your swap partition doesn't need to be bigger than your ram if you don't use suspend to disk. I even found an official help page recommending very small swap disks: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SwapFaq#How_much_swap_do_I_need.3F But better make it bigger to not run in any trouble.

Comment: in suspend to ram (the suspension you see in you shutdown / switch-user menu), there is no saving content of ram to swap, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Just chiming in --- suspend-to-disk is usually called **hibernation** in Linux-slang. Useful to find it with google.